# AS3 - Protected function error

Tags: actionscript-3

Since I put the "info.text = " into the function an unknown error comes up. 
Can someone please explain me what is wrong?

```
protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    if (currentVersion != updateVersion)
    {
        info.text = "Available..."
    } else {
        info.text = "Latest..."
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure you format your code as code (using the {} Button) instead of as comment (the " Button).

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you posted the error you receive.

Comment: Tom, you need to include the error code. I'm gonna downvote your question because it's so obvious. Once you edit and fix your question so people can actually answer it instead of people making random guesses (which I also downvoted), I'll remove my downvote. There could be any number of things. info object could be undefined in the scope of the function, info could be an object that doesn't have a text property or the property is restricted etc. Update with error code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take your question at face value and you're saying that there was no error before you added the "info.text =" line then this would be a good place to start investigating.

1. remove both lines and replace them with trace commands

   trace("Available");
   trace("Latest");

Test your movie and watch for traces in the output window. If that works we can progress.

1. If you are tracing out the correct messages we can assume the issue is to do with the textfield. So at the point of calling the function, make sure there is a textfield on the stage that has been assigned the instance name of "info".

Make sure that text field is a Dynamic type, (possibly assign a system font to the textfield such as Arial and set it to anti-alias "Use device fonts" to temporarily rule out any possibility that the error might be due to the font being used).

Let us know how you get on with that.

Answer (score -1):

If I am to read your code snippet **literally**; there is a syntax error.  It should be:

```
protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void { 
  if (currentVersion != updateVersion) { 
    info.text = "Available...";            //<<< Semicolon was missing
  } else{ 
    info.text = "Latest...";               //<<< Semicolon was missing
  } 
}
```

This assumes that `currentVersion`, `updateVersion` & `info` are declared elsewhere.

Comment: Missing semicolons shouldnt cause syntax error in flex / flash.

Comment: @Jarno Learned something!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Check if you have something wrong in earlier lines ..like missing ),].} ..or perhaps " or '

EDIT:
I suppose its also possible you have extented class and there is already function named *completeHandler*

Comment: right :) ..i suppose this should have been comment.

Comment: and after all.. the question was: "what is wrong?" ..and there is nothing wrong, all after that, is just a bonus. So i have to flag your comment as unconstructive ;)

Comment: Okay by all means flag it. It is constructive and I'm sure a moderator will agree. Why? Because completely random guesses junk up the site. This is at least one of the fundamental reasons for the invention of downvoting. :) I mean no disrespect, by all means if you have something constructive to add please do. But having random guesses on answers really makes the site incredibly difficult for drive-by visitors who are looking for REAL solutions to specific problems. It's best for everyone. :)

Comment: good point.. that is actually why i like the site; dont need to read hundreds post before get the right answer.